# How to access jwt after login using msal.js adb2c

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, msal.js

After logging in using the MsalAuthenticationTemplate InteractionType.Redirect, how do I get the JWT returned after successful authentication? It does not seem to be included in the msal instance.

```
import { MsalProvider, MsalAuthenticationTemplate, useMsal, useAccount } from "@azure/msal-react";    
const { instance } = useMsal();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should call `acquireTokenSilent` each time you need an access token. You can read more in our [getting started doc](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/msal-react/docs/getting-started.md#acquiring-an-access-token) and also review the [msal-react-samples](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/tree/dev/samples/msal-react-samples)

Comment: Hi @ThomasNorling. Thanks for the answer. Would you know If I won't be able to access the initial JWT after login? Wanted to get confirmation on this part.

Comment: `acquireTokenSilent` will retrieve the token from the cache. If called directly after a login, or within the expiration it will return the same tokens that were returned by the login call

Answer (score 1):

Another way of getting the idToken(JWT) after successful login is to hook into the addEventCallback and check for EventType.LOGIN_SUCCESS.

```
const callbackId = instance.addEventCallback(message => {
   if (message.eventType === EventType.LOGIN_SUCCESS) {
       const { payload } = message;
       // Get idToken(JWT) from the payload.
       console.log(payload.idToken);
   }
})
```

https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/msal-browser/docs/events.md

Answer (score 0):

You can handle redirect / popup promise and get tokenResponse from that like this:

```
instance.handleRedirectPromise().then((tokenResponse) => {
  console.log('token', tokenResponse);
}).catch((error) => {
  console.error('error', error);
  // handle error, either in the library or coming back from the server
});
```